# MoveArmGoal with collision checking disabled?

Tags: ros, collision, pr2-arm-navigation, move-arm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to use move_arm to send the arm through some trajectory with perhaps some path constraints or something, but with collision checking disabled. What's the easiest way to do that? I've been fiddling with [arm_navigation_msgs/OrderedCollisionOperations](http://www.ros.org/doc/electric/api/arm_navigation_msgs/html/msg/OrderedCollisionOperations.html) and setting the operation to 0 for "all" but that doesn't do anything, and I also tried setting things in [arm_navigation_msgs/AllowedCollisionMatrix](http://www.ros.org/doc/electric/api/arm_navigation_msgs/html/msg/AllowedCollisionMatrix.html) but that didn't work either. Any tips? Incidentally, I'm curious what these messages are supposed to be for, even if they aren't what I want. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12397/movearmgoal-with-collision-checking-disabled?/) by [Ibrahim](https://answers.ros.org/users/331/ibrahim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 307 on 2011-12-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Create a CollisionOperation op and set:

op.object1 = op.COLLISION_SET_ALL

op.object2 = op.COLLISION_SET_ALL

op.operation = op.DISABLE

and add it to the MoveArmGoal.

It sounds like you already tried something similar, but these can be tricky to get exactly right (for example using "all" or all instead of op.COLLISION_SET_ALL doesn't work) so I'd recommend trying it again.  I use the collision operations frequently with MoveArm and they do work in the way you expect.

Note that you need to pass the collision operation as part of the move arm goal; it won't work to set the planning scene because MoveArm resets it.

---

Originally posted by [jbarry](https://answers.ros.org/users/486/jbarry/) with karma: 280 on 2011-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ibrahim](https://answers.ros.org/users/331/ibrahim/) on 2011-12-19**:
Ah, I forgot to set object2, and then realized that it was nearly 6am and I should go to sleep. Cool, will try this out in a bit.